# Python how to apply .replace in data frame for a large amount of values to be changed

Tags: python, regex, pandas, numpy

#### How can I execute the task below in a more efficient way?

I have two data frames; df1 has my original data and df2 has keys that needs to be updated in df1.

#### The problem is that there are about 2000 names that need to be changed.

```
cw=

    id      adgroup      cost  
    1001    GoogleMaps   101,1
    1002    Google       101,1
    1003    AppStore     101,1
    1004    GoogleDocs   101,1


reff_table=

    adgroup       new_adgroup       
    GoogleMaps    G_maps
    Google        GG
    AppStore      APG
    GoogleDocs    DOC
```

This is how I am doing it:

```
m1 = cw.loc[cw['adgroup']=='GoogleMaps'].replace({'GoogleMaps' :'G_maps'})
m2 = cw.loc[cw['adgroup']=='GoogleMaps'].replace({'Google' :'GG'})

final_cw = pd.concat([m1, m2)]
```

Doing this manually is a long process, I need find more efficient way to get it done.

Comment: You should just join the 2 dataframes on `adgroup`, then `new_adgroup` becomes your new `adgroup` column with the correct renamed values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a merge/join

Your original dataframe:

```
print(df1)

     id     adgroup  cost
0  1001  GoogleMaps   101
1  1002  GoogleMaps   101
2  1003      Google   101
3  1004    AppStore   101
4  1005    AppStore   101
5  1006  GoogleDocs   101
```

You dataframe containing your references:

```
print(df2)

      adgroup new_adgroup
0  GoogleMaps      G_Maps
1      Google          GG
2    AppStore         APG
3  GoogleDocs         DOC
```

Merge them on `adgroup` will align the reference values to the correct rows in your original data (then you can drop/rename/reorder columns as you wish):

```
df1.merge(df2, on='adgroup').drop(columns=['adgroup']).rename(columns={'new_adgroup':'adgroup'})

     id  cost adgroup
0  1001   101  G_Maps
1  1002   101  G_Maps
2  1003   101      GG
3  1004   101     APG
4  1005   101     APG
5  1006   101     DOC
```

## Join methods

Lets say your original and reference dataframes are not a perfect match - how do you handle the extra/missing rows?

There are a number of join methods available to you: `left`, `right`, `outer`, `inner`

The Pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) has a brief explanation of these, but lets say your reference dataframe was missing the `adgroup` code for `AppStore` (the same idea applies if your original dataframe is also missing something) and looks like this:

```
      adgroup new_adgroup
0  GoogleMaps      G_Maps
1      Google          GG
2  GoogleDocs         DOC
```

What happens to the `AppStore` rows in your original data? Well, you can control that...

If you want to prioritize your original data and make sure you keep those rows, you can use a `left` join, and you will simply have `NA` values for the missing codes:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='adgroup', how='left')

     id  cost adgroup
0  1001   101  G_Maps
1  1002   101  G_Maps
2  1003   101      GG
3  1004   101     NaN
4  1005   101     NaN
5  1006   101     DOC
```

If instead you want to prioritize your reference dataframe, such that only the codes found in the reference are in your output, you can use a `right` join. Notice that because `AppStore` is not in your reference dataframe, the `AppStore` rows from your original data are removed:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='adgroup', how='right')

     id  cost adgroup
0  1001   101  G_Maps
1  1002   101  G_Maps
2  1003   101      GG
3  1006   101     DOC
```

Comment: @thanks Simon, so lets say for example there are few rows that do not match, can write something in the code to ignore and join whatever match?

Comment: yep so that just comes down to `how` you join. Your options are `left`, `right`, `outer`, `inner`. Which one you choose depends on which dataframe you want to prioritize and keep the non-matching values for. For example, `df1.merge(df2, on='adgroup', how='left')` would prioritize your original data, so if it has a name that is not in the reference table, it will still be in the new dataframe (it just will contain an NA value for the missing reference)

Comment: the pandas doc has an explanation of this (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), or just read up generally on how database joins work

Comment: @Peter for the sake of completeness I added a brief explanation of join methods to address your concern about mismatching/missing rows (see my edit)

Answer (score 1):

Given the following input:

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame([['GoogleMaps', 100, 1], ['Google', 200, 2], ['PlayStore', 300, 3]], columns=['ad_group', 'cost', 'id'])

df_new_index = pd.DataFrame([['GoogleMaps', 'GMaps'], ['Google', 'GG'], ['PlayStore', 'PS']], columns=['ad_group', 'new_ad_group'])
```

Try this one-line code:

```
df_data.ad_group = df_data.ad_group.map(df_new_index.set_index('ad_group')['new_ad_group'])
```

and gives:

```
  ad_group  cost  id
0    GMaps   100   1
1       GG   200   2
2       PS   300   3
```

If you set the index to the `'ad_group'` column on the other dataframe then you can replace using [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function on your original dataframe `'ad_group'` column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Series.replace`

```
cw['adgroup']=cw['adgroup'].replace(reff_table.set_index('adgroup')['new_adgroup'])
```

Comment: ,thanks, so lets say for example there are few rows in df(table_reff) that do not match with df(cw) , can write something in the code to ignore and join whatever match? keeping original df values as well